# Do upvotes beyond the daily reputation cap count for badges?

Tags: support, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit, tag-badges

I reached the daily rep cap, but keep getting upvotes. Do they count for getting my eagerly desired tag-specific badges?

(With the 100+ for joining meta, that's 360 in a day, wow.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, upvotes will still count towards badges.  Congrats on hitting the reputation cap.

Comment: Beating me by 23 seconds!!!!!!!!111

Comment: Drugs are bad for you, man.

Comment: I just got two badges (missing 40 rep), so I'll trust you on this one. Watch out with drugs.

Answer (score 2):

Why yes, they do.

Why on Earth would you think that they wouldn't?

Comment: It's a reasonable question, why on Earth would you respond so strongly?