# Are upvotes capped also when counting towards tag badges?

Tags: support, tags, badges, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do upvotes beyond the daily reputation cap count for badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68750/do-upvotes-beyond-the-daily-reputation-cap-count-for-badges)

I checked Meta Stack Overflow, but I didn't find an answer to this one.

When I reach the maximum reputation for the day, upvotes don't bring you reputation.
Are they counted for tag badges?

I mean for the badges that require 100/400/1.000 points in the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they are not capped, so yes, they will count.

Only reputation is capped, not the votes themselves. Since the tag badges are awarded based on answer score, irrespective of reputation, the daily reputation cap has no impact on the awarding process.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, votes earned after the cap are counted toward these badges.

Remember though, those badges also require a minimum number of posts to qualify.  So for the bronze C# badge, you need 100 upvotes **and also** 20 posts, silver is 400 and 80 posts, and gold is 1,000 and 200 posts.